# Updated support library, now resource files are not recognized by an Activity - Android

Tags: android, eclipse

This is a tricky problem. I imported a friend's project into Eclipse, and it was full of errors. At first there was a 'Jar mismatch!' that was due to an appcompat_v7 library (auto-imported to every single Eclipse project I use due to 22.6 upgrade) and an android.support.app.v4 library conflict. so i deleted the android.support.app.v4 library in the libs folder since i saw the v7 also included a v4. this made the jar mismatch go away. but then on one Activity, the ActionBarActivity as a class extension was not being recognised. i rolled over it and it said i could fix it by importing appcompat_v7 (which was odd since i thought it was already there by default and clearly was causing a conflict). So i clicked on it and imported it, and that error went away.

But now, none of my layout names in my xml (that are sourced in the Activity) are being recognized, even though the names are all correct and the correct code is there. e.g.

```
mSpnImageSize = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnImageSize);
```

spnImageSize has the error on it, saying it cannot be resolved to a field. But I know the xml file is fine, and has that field name in it.

Why is this happening? The project worked perfectly in my friend's computer, so I don't see why it is not working on mine. I also checked my SDK packages and they are all imported (both the support libraries and the API # that my project targets, as well as many other APIs).

Ever since I updated Eclipse to 22.6 (terrible update) I can no longer import other people's projects without all these crazy errors. Thanks in advance for your help.

**Here is my Activity file and my activity_layout file, just to show they are okay.**

```
package com.laurengariepy.android.gridimagesearch;

import android.R;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.text.Selection;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class FilterActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    protected static final String FILTERS = "FilterPreferences";

    private Spinner  mSpnImageSize,
                     mSpnColorFilter,
                     mSpnImageType;
    private EditText mEtSiteFilter;
    private Button   mBtnSave;

    private ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> aImageSizeAdapter,
                                       aColorFilterAdapter,
                                       aImageTypeAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_filter);

        setupViews();
        restoreFilterPreferences();
        setCursor();
    }

    private void setupViews() {
        mSpnImageSize = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnImageSize); 
        aImageSizeAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.image_size_options, 
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        aImageSizeAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        mSpnImageSize.setAdapter(aImageSizeAdapter); 

        mSpnColorFilter = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnColorFilter); 
        aColorFilterAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.color_filter_options,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item); 
        aColorFilterAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); 
        mSpnColorFilter.setAdapter(aColorFilterAdapter); 

        mSpnImageType = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnImageType);
        aImageTypeAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.image_type_options, 
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        aImageTypeAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        mSpnImageType.setAdapter(aImageTypeAdapter); 

        mEtSiteFilter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etSiteFilter);

        mBtnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
        mBtnSave.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent();
                setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

    private void restoreFilterPreferences() {
        SharedPreferences filters = getSharedPreferences(FILTERS, 0); 

        int imageSizeSelection = filters.getInt("image_size", 0);  
        mSpnImageSize.setSelection(imageSizeSelection); 

        int colorFilterSelection = filters.getInt("color_filter", 0); 
        mSpnColorFilter.setSelection(colorFilterSelection);

        int imageTypeSelection = filters.getInt("image_type", 0); 
        mSpnImageType.setSelection(imageTypeSelection);

        String siteFilterSelection = filters.getString("site_filter", mEtSiteFilter.getHint().toString()); 
        mEtSiteFilter.setText(siteFilterSelection);
    }

    private void setCursor() {
        int position = mEtSiteFilter.length();
        Selection.setSelection(mEtSiteFilter.getText(), position); 
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause(); 
        saveFilterPreferences(); 
    }

    private void saveFilterPreferences() {
        SharedPreferences filters = getSharedPreferences(FILTERS, 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = filters.edit();
        editor.putInt("image_size", mSpnImageSize.getSelectedItemPosition()); 
        editor.putInt("color_filter", mSpnColorFilter.getSelectedItemPosition());
        editor.putInt("image_type", mSpnImageType.getSelectedItemPosition()); 
        editor.putString("site_filter", mEtSiteFilter.getText().toString()); 
        editor.commit(); 
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.filter, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

**The accompanying xml file:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvFilterHeader"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"       
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:text="@string/tv_filter_header" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvImageSize"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvFilterHeader"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text="@string/tv_image_size" />

     <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spnImageSize"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tvImageSize"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvImageSize"
        android:textSize="18sp" 
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvColorFilter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvImageSize"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text="@string/tv_color_filter" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spnColorFilter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tvColorFilter"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvColorFilter"
        android:textSize="18sp" 
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvImageType"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvColorFilter"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text="@string/tv_image_type" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spnImageType"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tvImageType"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvImageType"
        android:textSize="18sp" 
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSiteFilter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvImageType"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text="@string/tv_site_filter" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etSiteFilter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tvSiteFilter"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvSiteFilter"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/et_filter_hint" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSave"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvSiteFilter"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:text="@string/btn_save" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: there must be errors in your resources files. R.java is not generated. fix the errors and clean and build the project

Comment: thanks Raghunandan... that's what you would think, but I tell you, it's my friend's project and it worked totally fine on his computer. there is something else, weird going on here. i will post my files to prove, they are okay... i wish it were as simple as that, honestly. :/

Comment: just found the mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this

```
import android.R;
```

You imported R from the android framework.

Instead it should be

```
import com.laurengariepy.android.gridimagesearch.R;
// your packagename.R
```

Comment: Oh thanks so much!! you know how that happened, is when I thought all the errors were an import problem (which they sort of were), i did the shift+command+O and that `import android.R;` thing showed up on its own... then I forgot that even happened because it took me a while to figure out the library problem. but this was the last piece of the puzzle. thank you so so much!!!